# backbone.js on tablet/mobile and debugging

Tags: android, debugging, backbone.js

I'm building my first backbone.js app, and was a bit disappointed with the performance in chrome, but figured I'd optimize when I got further along.

I just tried viewing the app on my tablet (touchpad running android 2.3.7), and I don't get ANY of the javascript elements loading. I don't know if this is because of a bug, or maybe my backbone files are too large??

Any idea what would cause this, and how I would go about debugging? 
The console on the desktop shows no errors.

Answer (score 1):

apparently you can use console on android as well with a certain tool called logcat

you can find more information on this link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [WEINRE](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre).

The setup might be kind of a challenge, but when it works, it does work great.

It gives you the webkit inspector on your computer screen, live connected to the app on your device.

Jonathan Stark gives a nice intro in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nL6xey13fE

Edit: If you don't like weinre, you could always use RIM's [RIPPLE](http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/).

Ripple emulates most devices' mobile browsers. I don't really like it though because the ux-emulation you get is often way of the real thing.